# Reading XML with multiple levels

Tags: c#, xml

I am trying to read the below XML using C# as DataTable to get `LinkedTxn`, `RefNumber` if the `TxnType` is `BillPaymentCheck`. The `LinkedTxn` sometime may come as `<TxnType>PurchaseOrder</TxnType>` as well, but I want to get only for `<TxnType>BillPaymentCheck</TxnType>`. This may come 2/3 times for `BillRet` level.

If 2/3 `LinkedTxn` sections are there, then need to have 2/3 datarows in the datatable.

[XML Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EtYvG.png)

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<QBXML>
  <QBXMLMsgsRs>
    <BillQueryRs requestID="0" statusCode="0" statusSeverity="Info" statusMessage="Status OK">
      <BillRet>
        <TxnID>3F9C-1071507206</TxnID>
        <TimeCreated>2003-12-15T22:23:26+05:30</TimeCreated>
        <TimeModified>2016-12-15T14:18:52+05:30</TimeModified>
        <EditSequence>1481791723</EditSequence>
        <TxnNumber>857</TxnNumber>
        <VendorRef>
          <ListID>B0000-933272656</ListID>
          <FullName>Patton Hardware Supplies</FullName>
        </VendorRef>
        <APAccountRef>
          <ListID>C0000-933270541</ListID>
          <FullName>Accounts Payable</FullName>
        </APAccountRef>
        <TxnDate>2017-06-13</TxnDate>
        <DueDate>2018-07-13</DueDate>
        <AmountDue>1214.89</AmountDue>
        <TermsRef>
          <ListID>10000-933272658</ListID>
          <FullName>Net 30</FullName>
        </TermsRef>
        <IsPaid>true</IsPaid>
        <LinkedTxn>
          <TxnID>42A2-1071524160</TxnID>
          <TxnType>BillPaymentCheck</TxnType>
          <TxnDate>2017-08-08</TxnDate>
          <RefNumber>371</RefNumber>
          <LinkType>AMTTYPE</LinkType>
          <Amount>-1214.89</Amount>
        </LinkedTxn>
        <OpenAmount>3459.20</OpenAmount>
      </BillRet>
      <BillRet>
        <TxnID>3F36-1071505009</TxnID>
        <TimeCreated>2003-12-15T21:46:49+05:30</TimeCreated>
        <TimeModified>2016-12-15T14:18:51+05:30</TimeModified>
        <EditSequence>1481791721</EditSequence>
        <TxnNumber>847</TxnNumber>
        <VendorRef>
          <ListID>B0000-933272656</ListID>
          <FullName>Patton Hardware Supplies</FullName>
        </VendorRef>
        <APAccountRef>
          <ListID>C0000-933270541</ListID>
          <FullName>Accounts Payable</FullName>
        </APAccountRef>
        <TxnDate>2017-06-15</TxnDate>
        <DueDate>2018-07-15</DueDate>
        <AmountDue>1109.15</AmountDue>
        <TermsRef>
          <ListID>10000-933272658</ListID>
          <FullName>Net 30</FullName>
        </TermsRef>
        <IsPaid>true</IsPaid>
        <LinkedTxn>
          <TxnID>429D-1071524130</TxnID>
          <TxnType>BillPaymentCheck</TxnType>
          <TxnDate>2017-06-25</TxnDate>
          <RefNumber>338</RefNumber>
          <LinkType>AMTTYPE</LinkType>
          <Amount>-1109.15</Amount>
        </LinkedTxn>
        <OpenAmount>3459.20</OpenAmount>
      </BillRet>
      <BillRet>
        <TxnID>325C-1071513076</TxnID>
        <TimeCreated>2003-12-16T00:01:16+05:30</TimeCreated>
        <TimeModified>2016-12-15T14:17:53+05:30</TimeModified>
        <EditSequence>1481791672</EditSequence>
        <TxnNumber>547</TxnNumber>
        <VendorRef>
          <ListID>B0000-933272656</ListID>
          <FullName>Patton Hardware Supplies</FullName>
        </VendorRef>
        <APAccountRef>
          <ListID>C0000-933270541</ListID>
          <FullName>Accounts Payable</FullName>
        </APAccountRef>
        <TxnDate>2017-07-30</TxnDate>
        <DueDate>2018-08-29</DueDate>
        <AmountDue>754.50</AmountDue>
        <RefNumber>35698</RefNumber>
        <TermsRef>
          <ListID>10000-933272658</ListID>
          <FullName>Net 30</FullName>
        </TermsRef>
        <IsPaid>true</IsPaid>
        <LinkedTxn>
          <TxnID>3258-1071513042</TxnID>
          <TxnType>PurchaseOrder</TxnType>
          <TxnDate>2017-07-23</TxnDate>
          <RefNumber>6207</RefNumber>
          <LinkType>QUANTYPE</LinkType>
          <Amount>0.00</Amount>
        </LinkedTxn>
        <LinkedTxn>
          <TxnID>326A-1071513156</TxnID>
          <TxnType>BillPaymentCheck</TxnType>
          <TxnDate>2017-12-15</TxnDate>
          <RefNumber>503</RefNumber>
          <LinkType>AMTTYPE</LinkType>
          <Amount>-754.50</Amount>
        </LinkedTxn>
        <OpenAmount>3459.20</OpenAmount>
      </BillRet>
      <BillRet>
        <TxnID>3F33-1071504970</TxnID>
        <TimeCreated>2003-12-15T21:46:10+05:30</TimeCreated>
        <TimeModified>2016-12-15T14:18:44+05:30</TimeModified>
        <EditSequence>1481791721</EditSequence>
        <TxnNumber>846</TxnNumber>
        <VendorRef>
          <ListID>B0000-933272656</ListID>
          <FullName>Patton Hardware Supplies</FullName>
        </VendorRef>
        <APAccountRef>
          <ListID>C0000-933270541</ListID>
          <FullName>Accounts Payable</FullName>
        </APAccountRef>
        <TxnDate>2017-11-01</TxnDate>
        <DueDate>2018-12-01</DueDate>
        <AmountDue>656.23</AmountDue>
        <TermsRef>
          <ListID>10000-933272658</ListID>
          <FullName>Net 30</FullName>
        </TermsRef>
        <IsPaid>true</IsPaid>
        <LinkedTxn>
          <TxnID>3FB5-1071507296</TxnID>
          <TxnType>BillPaymentCheck</TxnType>
          <TxnDate>2017-11-30</TxnDate>
          <RefNumber>472</RefNumber>
          <LinkType>AMTTYPE</LinkType>
          <Amount>-656.23</Amount>
        </LinkedTxn>
        <OpenAmount>3459.20</OpenAmount>
      </BillRet>
      <BillRet>
        <TxnID>A16-933373605</TxnID>
        <TimeCreated>1999-07-31T03:56:45+05:30</TimeCreated>
        <TimeModified>2016-12-15T14:18:05+05:30</TimeModified>
        <EditSequence>1481791619</EditSequence>
        <TxnNumber>191</TxnNumber>
        <VendorRef>
          <ListID>B0000-933272656</ListID>
          <FullName>Patton Hardware Supplies</FullName>
        </VendorRef>
        <APAccountRef>
          <ListID>C0000-933270541</ListID>
          <FullName>Accounts Payable</FullName>
        </APAccountRef>
        <TxnDate>2017-11-17</TxnDate>
        <DueDate>2018-12-17</DueDate>
        <AmountDue>325.00</AmountDue>
        <TermsRef>
          <ListID>10000-933272658</ListID>
          <FullName>Net 30</FullName>
        </TermsRef>
        <IsPaid>true</IsPaid>
        <LinkedTxn>
          <TxnID>36AD-1071520917</TxnID>
          <TxnType>BillPaymentCheck</TxnType>
          <TxnDate>2017-12-05</TxnDate>
          <RefNumber>484</RefNumber>
          <LinkType>AMTTYPE</LinkType>
          <Amount>-325.00</Amount>
        </LinkedTxn>
        <OpenAmount>3459.20</OpenAmount>
      </BillRet>
      <BillRet>
        <TxnID>40C1-1071514252</TxnID>
        <TimeCreated>2003-12-16T00:20:52+05:30</TimeCreated>
        <TimeModified>2016-12-15T14:18:51+05:30</TimeModified>
        <EditSequence>1481791728</EditSequence>
        <TxnNumber>891</TxnNumber>
        <VendorRef>
          <ListID>B0000-933272656</ListID>
          <FullName>Patton Hardware Supplies</FullName>
        </VendorRef>
        <APAccountRef>
          <ListID>C0000-933270541</ListID>
          <FullName>Accounts Payable</FullName>
        </APAccountRef>
        <TxnDate>2017-12-01</TxnDate>
        <DueDate>2018-12-31</DueDate>
        <AmountDue>400.00</AmountDue>
        <TermsRef>
          <ListID>10000-933272658</ListID>
          <FullName>Net 30</FullName>
        </TermsRef>
        <IsPaid>true</IsPaid>
        <LinkedTxn>
          <TxnID>428C-1071523939</TxnID>
          <TxnType>BillPaymentCheck</TxnType>
          <TxnDate>2017-12-15</TxnDate>
          <RefNumber>512</RefNumber>
          <LinkType>AMTTYPE</LinkType>
          <Amount>-400.00</Amount>
        </LinkedTxn>
        <OpenAmount>3459.20</OpenAmount>
      </BillRet>
      <BillRet>
        <TxnID>863D-1197708527</TxnID>
        <TimeCreated>2007-12-15T14:18:47+05:30</TimeCreated>
        <TimeModified>2017-12-15T22:44:33+05:30</TimeModified>
        <EditSequence>1481791803</EditSequence>
        <TxnNumber>1415</TxnNumber>
        <VendorRef>
          <ListID>B0000-933272656</ListID>
          <FullName>Patton Hardware Supplies</FullName>
        </VendorRef>
        <APAccountRef>
          <ListID>C0000-933270541</ListID>
          <FullName>Accounts Payable</FullName>
        </APAccountRef>
        <TxnDate>2017-12-01</TxnDate>
        <DueDate>2018-12-31</DueDate>
        <AmountDue>210.00</AmountDue>
        <TermsRef>
          <ListID>10000-933272658</ListID>
          <FullName>Net 30</FullName>
        </TermsRef>
        <IsPaid>true</IsPaid>
        <LinkedTxn>
          <TxnID>1B953-1513358073</TxnID>
          <TxnType>BillPaymentCheck</TxnType>
          <TxnDate>2017-12-15</TxnDate>
          <LinkType>AMTTYPE</LinkType>
          <Amount>-210.00</Amount>
        </LinkedTxn>
        <OpenAmount>3459.20</OpenAmount>
      </BillRet>
      <BillRet>
        <TxnID>F34-933787718</TxnID>
        <TimeCreated>1999-08-04T22:58:38+05:30</TimeCreated>
        <TimeModified>2017-12-15T23:26:55+05:30</TimeModified>
        <EditSequence>1481791630</EditSequence>
        <TxnNumber>290</TxnNumber>
        <VendorRef>
          <ListID>B0000-933272656</ListID>
          <FullName>Patton Hardware Supplies</FullName>
        </VendorRef>
        <APAccountRef>
          <ListID>C0000-933270541</ListID>
          <FullName>Accounts Payable</FullName>
        </APAccountRef>
        <TxnDate>2017-12-12</TxnDate>
        <DueDate>2019-01-11</DueDate>
        <AmountDue>810.00</AmountDue>
        <TermsRef>
          <ListID>10000-933272658</ListID>
          <FullName>Net 30</FullName>
        </TermsRef>
        <IsPaid>true</IsPaid>
        <LinkedTxn>
          <TxnID>1BD52-1513360613</TxnID>
          <TxnType>BillPaymentCheck</TxnType>
          <TxnDate>2017-12-15</TxnDate>
          <LinkType>AMTTYPE</LinkType>
          <Amount>-810.00</Amount>
        </LinkedTxn>
        <OpenAmount>3459.20</OpenAmount>
      </BillRet>
    </BillQueryRs>
  </QBXMLMsgsRs>
</QBXML>
```

coded like the following,

```
foreach (XmlNode chlnode in invoiceElement.ChildNodes)
{
    if (chlnode.Name == "LinkedTxn")
    {
        if (Convert.ToString(chlnode["TxnType"].InnerText) == "BillPaymentCheck")
        {
            //RefNumber
            if (chlnode["RefNumber"] != null)
            {

                d["CheckNum"] = Convert.ToString(chlnode["RefNumber"].InnerText);
                if (count == 0)
                {
                    dtTemp.Rows.Add(d);
                }
                else
                {
                    d = dtTemp.NewRow();
                    d["CheckNum"] = Convert.ToString(chlnode["RefNumber"].InnerText);
                    dtTemp.Rows.Add(d);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //dtTemp.Rows.Add(d);
        }
    }
}
```

But not working, returning same row for all records.

Comment: What is invoiceElement in this code??

Comment: I recommend you to have a look at `XDocument`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try folllowing xml linq

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("TxnID",typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("TimeCreated",typeof(DateTime));
            dt.Columns.Add("TimeModified",typeof(DateTime));
            dt.Columns.Add("EditSequence",typeof(long));
            dt.Columns.Add("TxnNumber",typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("VendorListID",typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("VendorFullName",typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("APAccountListID", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("APAccountFullName", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("TxnDate", typeof(DateTime));
            dt.Columns.Add("DueDate",typeof(DateTime));
            dt.Columns.Add("AmountDue",typeof(decimal));

            dt.Columns.Add("TermsListID",typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("TermsFullName",typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("IsPaid",typeof(Boolean));


            dt.Columns.Add("LinkedTxnID", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("LinkedTxnType", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("LinkedTxnDate", typeof(DateTime));
            dt.Columns.Add("LinkedRefNumber", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns["LinkedRefNumber"].AllowDBNull = true;
            dt.Columns.Add("LinkType",typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Amount",typeof(decimal));
            dt.Columns.Add("OpenAmount", typeof(decimal));

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            foreach (XElement billRet in doc.Descendants("BillRet"))
            {
                string txnID = (string)billRet.Element("TxnID");
                DateTime timeCreated = (DateTime)billRet.Element("TimeCreated");
                DateTime timeModified = (DateTime)billRet.Element("TimeModified");
                long editSequence = (long)billRet.Element("EditSequence");
                int TxnNumber = (int)billRet.Element("TxnNumber");
                string vendorListID = (string)billRet.Element("VendorRef").Element("ListID");
                string vendorFullName = (string)billRet.Element("VendorRef").Element("FullName");
                string apAccountListID = (string)billRet.Element("APAccountRef").Element("ListID");
                string apAccountFullName = (string)billRet.Element("APAccountRef").Element("FullName");
                DateTime txnDate = (DateTime)billRet.Element("TxnDate");
                DateTime dueDate = (DateTime)billRet.Element("DueDate");
                string termsListID = (string)billRet.Element("TermsRef").Element("ListID");
                string termsFullName = (string)billRet.Element("TermsRef").Element("FullName");
                decimal amountDue = (decimal)billRet.Element("AmountDue");
                decimal openAmount = (decimal)billRet.Element("OpenAmount");
                Boolean isPaid = (Boolean)billRet.Element("IsPaid");



                foreach (XElement linkedTxn in billRet.Elements("LinkedTxn"))
                {
                    DataRow newRow = dt.Rows.Add();

                    newRow["TxnID"] = txnID;
                    newRow["TimeCreated"] = timeCreated;
                    newRow["TimeModified"] = timeModified;
                    newRow["EditSequence"] = editSequence;
                    newRow["TxnNumber"] = TxnNumber;
                    newRow["VendorListID"] = vendorListID;
                    newRow["VendorFullName"] = vendorFullName;
                    newRow["APAccountListID"] = apAccountListID;
                    newRow["APAccountFullName"] = apAccountFullName;
                    newRow["TxnDate"] = txnDate;
                    newRow["DueDate"] = dueDate;
                    newRow["TermsListID"] = termsListID ;
                    newRow["TermsFullName"] = termsFullName;
                    newRow["AmountDue"] = amountDue;
                    newRow["OpenAmount"] = openAmount;
                    newRow["IsPaid"] = isPaid;

                    newRow["LinkedTxnID"] = (string)linkedTxn.Element("TxnID");
                    newRow["LinkedTxnType"] = (string)linkedTxn.Element("TxnType");
                    newRow["LinkedTxnDate"] = (DateTime)linkedTxn.Element("TxnDate");
                    if(linkedTxn.Element("RefNumber") != null)
                       newRow["LinkedRefNumber"] = (int)linkedTxn.Element("RefNumber");
                    newRow["LinkType"] = (string)linkedTxn.Element("LinkType");
                    newRow["Amount"] = (decimal)linkedTxn.Element("Amount");

                }

            }
        }

    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are unaware of XPath.

```
// all linked transactions that are bill payment checks and have a RefNumber
var xpath = "//BillRet/LinkedTxn[TxnType = 'BillPaymentCheck' and RefNumber > 0]";

foreach (var linkedTxn in invoiceElement.SelectNodes(xpath)) {
    var d = dtTemp.NewRow();
    d["CheckNum"] = linkedTxn["RefNumber"].InnerText;
    dtTemp.Rows.Add(d)
}
```

See the [`XmlNode.SelectNodes` Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.selectnodes(v=vs.110).aspx). Reading up on XPath will save you a lot of time and typing.